# Is a class with properties but no logic unit testable?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

I have a class as below. Is this a candidate for unit tests by itself?
What kind of tests / coverage can I write for this class?

```
public class Cart : ICart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ABCCompany Company { get; set; }
    public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountValue { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountedSubtotal{ get; set; }
    public ICartDiscounts Discounts { get; set; }
    public IList<ICartItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Any unit tests would be trivial - they would only be able to demonstrate that the object is able to hold & regurgitate any state set via the gets and sets (ie testing the reliability of auto properties)  As an aside, unless you do intend implementing multiple subclasses of ICart, interface abstractions on Pocos are usually a [smell](https://lostechies.com/jamesgregory/2009/05/09/entity-interface-anti-pattern/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has no logic to test so... no; its not really unit testable.

One could argue that the getters and setters could be tested; but there is really no point in doing so since the logic is framework provided.